# Python script will not run in Task Scheduler for "Run whether use is logged on or not"

Tags: python, automation, task, scheduler

I have written a python script and wanted to have it run at a set period everyday with the use of Task Scheduler. I have had no problems with Task Scheduler for running programs while logged off, before creating this task.

If I select "Run only when user is logged on" my script runs as expected with the desired result and no error code (0x0).

If I select "Run whether user is logged on or not" with "Run with highest privileges" and then leave it overnight or log off to test it, it does not do anything and has an error code of 0x1.

I have the action to "Start a program" with the Details as follows:

**Program/script**: C:\Python27\python2.7.exe
**Add arguments**: "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.py"

I think it has to do with permissions to use python while logged off but I can't figure this one out. Wondering if anyone has suggestions or experience on this.

***This is on Windows 7 (fyi)***

Thanks,
JP

Comment: Yes, I am modifying CSV files that are within my user directory. Don't think they need permission to modify.

I don't know why this would be an issue though, because I also use the email task within scheduler to email files within my user directory...

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the solution to this problem. My script is used to create a powerpoint slide deck and needs to open MS PPT.

I stumbled upon a post from another forum with a link to MS's policy on this. It basically boils down to the following:

"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behaviour and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Automating PowerPoint from a scheduled task falls under the unsupported scenario when scheduled task is run with the option "Run whether user logged on or not". But, using it with "Run only when the user is logged on" option falls under the supported category."

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/d0fee207-846b-4908-bc85-a2fad8408c37/)

Comment: If anyone has any updates for working around these limitations, please share.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with the script not in your Users directory

Comment: Just tried running the script in the C:/ directory and then logged off my account. Same result 0x1.

Comment: I also tried to make a batch file to run the script. Again, when logged on it works, but if I let it run while I'm logged off, 0x1 error.

Answer (score 0):

create your windows task in task scheduler, then right click the task and select "export", export your task as MYTASK.xml.

Then create a bat file and input below in the bat file.
`schtasks.exe /Create /XML "MYTASK.xml" /tn MYTASK /RU ACCT_NAME_CHANGEME /RP *`

You can choose type in your password to replace the * symbol.

Then run the bat file and test to see whether your task running.

Answer (score -1):

I have experience supporting PowerPoint automation under the Task Scheduler by way of a C++ app called p3icli (available on sourceforge). This is the approach I successfully used:

1) Add a command-line (-T) switch that indicates p3icli will run under Task Scheduler.

2) The command-line switch forces p3icli to start an instance of powerpnt.exe using **CreateProcess()** and then wait X milliseconds for that instance to stabilize.

3) After X milliseconds elapse, p3icli connects to the running PPT instance created in step 2 and processes automation commands.

I would guess that a similar approach can be used with Python.

Task Scheduler compatibility is easily the most troublesome feature I ever added to p3icli.  For example, manipulating multiple presentations by changing the active window simply does not work.  And as I'm sure you've discovered, debugging problems is no fun at all.

NB: Your python solution must include code that forces PowerPoint to unconditionally close when your python script is complete (modulo a python crash).  Otherwise, orphaned instances of PowerPoint will appear in Task Manager.

Click the link for some thoughts on the Task Scheduler from a p3icli [point of view](http://p3icli.sourceforge.net/p3icli_help.html#task_scheduler_caveats).